Dividing nested calls into several lines
I have a function like this in Python (the capital letters can represent constants, functions, anything, but not function calls):
def f(x):
    a = foo1(A, B, foo3(E, foo2(A, B)))
    b = foo3(a, E)
    return b

and I want to break it up into "atomic" operations like this:
def f(x):
    tmp1 = foo2(A, B)
    tmp2 = foo3(E, tmp1)
    a = foo1(A, B, tmp2)
    b = foo3(a, E)
    return b

In other words, exactly one function call and one assignment per line.
Is there a way I can implement this source code transformation in Python? A program that takes in the string representation of such a function and returns the transformed version. I know I need to use the AST representation, but I don't really know how to proceed.

Sounds like a job for Regex. Add a tag to this question you'll get someone on the case.

I think this is what you want exactly:
s = """def f(x):
    a = foo1(A, B, foo3(E, foo2(A, B)))
    b = foo3(a, E)
    return b"""

import re

result = []
reg = re.compile(r'^(\s+).*?(\w+\([^\(\)]*\))')
count = 1
for l in s.splitlines():
    r = reg.search(l)
    if not r:
        result.append(l)
        continue
    while r:
        indent = r[1]
        var = f'tmp_{count}'
        result.append(f'{indent}{var} = {r[2]}')
        count += 1
        l = l[:r.start(2)] + var + l[r.end(2):]
        r = reg.search(l)
    else:
        if l.strip():
            result.append(l)


print('\n'.join(result))

and it will show:
def f(x):
    tmp_1 = foo2(A, B)
    tmp_2 = foo3(E, tmp_1)
    tmp_3 = foo1(A, B, tmp_2)
    a = tmp_3
    tmp_4 = foo3(a, E)
    b = tmp_4
    return b


Inside a character class, round brackets are no more special characters, so you can write [^()] instead of [^\(\)] (backslashes are ignored by the regex engine in this case).
